# Accept date and time field on queries

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-query-web-part, notifications

I created a date/hour field and the documents only appear on the page when the date is <=Today.
I set this on the query RefinableDate13 <={{undefined | amUtc | amDateFormat:'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'}} and works fine in webpart queries. But it seems that didn't work in the notification hub.

On the query of Notification Hub only work if I put RefinableDate13 <={Today}. But this isn't a solution, because it does not consider the hours. {Today} is set like 2021-04-15T00:00:00 and my refinableDate13 has an hour.

How can I do to accept that on the query of the notification hub?

The notification hub is the bell with the recent activities. But also don't work on the search.

[image]

Best regards.

Comment: This query also doesn't work on the search query.

Comment: Hi Cristina. Can you post a sceenshot? I am curious what you mean by Notification Hub.

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov I added on the post.